# Copy particular cell value using contextMenu in ExtJs 5.0 Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to copy content of paticular cell value using contextMenu in ExtJs 5.0.1

To be clear I have a Grid and added right click contextMenu as well. In contextMenu include copy options.
Now I want to copy particular cell Value while click on copy option from contextMenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to copy to the clipboard the text in a cell?

Here is a fiddle.

[ExtJS copy paste grid cell](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/394e)